# 'Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'TimeController'' error in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller, identifier

I am trying to send an Int from one view controller to another in swift, but I am getting this error. There is another post on this same topic, but the advice given is to 'clean' the project which does not work for me. Here is my code:

First view controller:

```
import UIKit

class UserInput: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var myInt = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        myInt = 5

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {

        let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TimeController") as! TimeController
        myVC.intPassed = myInt
        navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Second view controller:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TimeController: UIViewController {

    var intPassed = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(intPassed)

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: have you given the identifier to TimeController in the storyboard?

Comment: Have you tried to shutdown xcode and open it again? Sometimes it works with bugs in storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have inserted `TimeController` as the Storyboard ID in your storyboard.

[image]

Comment: then are you using the `storyboard` that includes your `TimeController`?

Comment: Yes, I am using it

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot to select TimeController as my "Restoration ID"

Comment: Good to know :)